# moving row within a table on draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

On draw.io, I am trying to move a row in a table, I grab the right hand equals sign on
the row to move, but when I move it to a new position the row snaps back
to its original position. I am using the online version on Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

When a row is dropped to early, it could snap to original position. Check the following article: https://drawio-app.com/tables-in-drawio-got-a-makeover/ In order to move row 4 to another place, it was drag&dropped slightly over the first row and it became the 2nd row.

Hopefully the article will help.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The equal like symbols, you hold them, and then you can reorder the rows in the tables.

For reordering columns, I checked and it's not yet a feature in draw.io, hopefully it will be a feature.

Comment: Your answer is already part of [the question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/153522/).

Comment: @Blindspots As someone who just wanted to know "how to move a row from table in draw.io" (which is the title of the post), this helped me.

Answer (score -1):

It's not really designed to work in this way. Just add a row, copy and paste the values, then delete the old row. 5 second job.

Draw.io works in objects. The object is a table in this scenario. It's not designed to move sub-objects (rows) from one object (table) to another object (table).

Draw.io is an awesome tool I used on a daily basis, but don't expect unicorns.